# Displaying the data export/feed icon only when there are search results

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I've got a data export attached to my view. Although it works what I want it to do... it displays under the search form even when there are no search results... How do I get around this?

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say "data export attached to my view" - Are you using a Views attachment display? Also, where is the export coming from?

Comment: What Drupal version? Please tag your question with a Drupal version.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the template for the views.

There is a variable called `$empty` this field contains the text to be displayed if the node is empty. You can use this to check if view is empty or not.

If you have placed the attachment before the node then you would edit the below section.

```
<?php if ($attachment_before): ?>
    <div class="attachment attachment-before">
      <?php print $attachment_before; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

You can change this to

```
<?php if ($attachment_before && !$empty): ?>
    <div class="attachment attachment-before">
      <?php print $attachment_before; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

This would make sure that the attachment is printed only if the view has a result.

Answer (score 1):

Without templating/theming, just using Views UI and having little skills on HTML, you can do next:

1. Open your page "my view". There you'll see export icon.
2. Copy source code of export icon, it should be like next: `<a href="url_of_export"><img src="icon_url" /></a>`. In firefox/chrome just right click on icon, and click View source, copy it.
3. Goto "my view" views editing.
4. Remove attachment from "Export" display to main view.
5. In main view display, add Footer and paste your html code from above. "Show even no results" should be unchecked.

Comment: I am not sure if this would work in the above case since he is using the data export which needs to be attached to the view for the filters to take effect on the data export.

Comment: usually export filters use the same filters from main view, in this case it will work. Otherwise, of course, theming...

Comment: This works only if there is no sorting criteria defined in views. Views_data_export can export also the sorted fields from views, but this approach doesn't export sorted fields

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_views_pre_render(&$view) {
    if($view->name == 'xxx')  {
        if($view->total_rows < 1) {
            unset($view->feed_icon);
        }
    }
}
```